# QProcess() doesn't always work

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to format an USB drive from Qt by using `mkfs.fat` with QProcess(). The problem is that QProcess() is called but sometimes it exits without finishing the formatting. If I read `exitCode()` it is 1.

This is the function:

```
bool UsbDevice::formatFat(QByteArray name)
{
    QProcess * formatter = new QProcess(this);

    QString partition = baDevice + "1"; // baDevice is "/dev/sdb"
    QString mkfs = "mkfs.fat";

    QStringList args;
    args << "-F32" << "-v" << "-I" << "-n " + name << partition;

    formatter->start(mkfs, args);

    formatter->waitForStarted();

    formatter->waitForFinished(-1);

    emit logLine(formatter->readAll());

    if (formatter->exitCode() == 0)
        {
            emit logLine("mkfs.fat executed correctly.");
        }
    else
        {
            emit logLine(QString("Possible fail to format device (Error: %1).").arg(formatter->errorString()));
        }

    delete formatter;

    return true;
}
```

The function works if it is called 3 - 5 times. I understand that there are more issues than this (for example this function blocks the user interface because of the `waitFor*` functions, and one of them can block forever without having a timeout) but I don't get it why the process doesn't finish Ok sometimes.

`logLine` calls `qDebug` and the output when it doesn't work is like:

```
mkfs.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)

Possible fail to format device (Error: Unknown error).
```

When it works, it outputs:

```
mkfs.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
/dev/sdb1 has 64 heads and 32 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x0800;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 30279937 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 16 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 14771 sectors, and provides 1890647 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is c35005fb, volume label  USB   .

mkfs.fat executed correctly.
```

This makes me think the arguments are correct.

I have also tried connecting `finished()` signal to a slot and block until the signal is emitted, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you try the output of `readAllStandardError()`?

Comment: @Wimmel yes, thank you, I guess this solves the problem. The output is `/dev/sdb1: No such file or directory`. Now I must figure out what prevents acces to `/dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not very clear about this, but it looks like [readAll](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) has the same output as [readAllStandardOutput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput). Software typically outputs errors on stderr (StandardError), so you would have to call [readAllStandardError](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError) to see the error message. So there is nothing wrong with `QProcess()`, it is just `mkfs.fat` which fails.